# Using FileMaker Pro to read/write to csv automatically

Tags: csv, filemaker

I have a CSV file which is designed to sit in the middle of various systems that utilise it. For example, I have a python script that runs and updates data in the CSV periodically.

I'm looking to have a UI that uses the CSV data and allows the user to filter it and perform various other actions.

However I've not been able to find a clear answer online regarding the refreshing of imported CSV data File. I can see how you import the data, but can you have it so it refreshes (so it reflects any changes made to the CSV) every x amount of seconds/minutes or even when the file itself is modified?

And vice-versa, can the user edit something in the table on FileMaker and have the CSV also be updated to reflect that (either upon changing something or when a button is clicked)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options.

1. Run the import/export as a scheduled script every x minutes on FileMaker Server.
2. Install an ontimer script on Filemaker Pro that runs your import/export script every x minutes as long as the window is open.
3. Trigger the import/export script from an external source, for instance Applescript or Active x.